# How to have a clickable text box appear over an image on hover

Tags: javascript, html, css

I have an image inside of a DIV.  When a user hovers over the image I would like a white box with 65% opacity to come up from the bottom of the image that would only cover a about 30% of the bottom of the image.  In that box would be text that say something like "+ Order Sample" and when the user clicks on that box it would be added to the cart.

Easy enough to handle the adding to cart part it's the css and possibly javascript necessary to make this happen that I'm struggling with.  Can someone get me started?  Here's what I have so far.  This includes edits from first answer.

```
foreach($array as $key => $value) {
    $imgsrc = $value['option_value']. ".jpg" ;
    $option_name = $value['option_name'] ;
    $fullname = $value['quality'] . " " . $value['color'] ; 
    $cbpg = $value['cbpg'] ;
    $space = $value['space'] ;

    print "<div class='colorbook-color-guide-div' onmouseover='showOrderSample();'>" ;
      print "<img class='colorbook-color-guide-image js-color-option js-tooltip' nopin='nopin' data-tooltip-content='$option_name' src='/images/uploads/colors/$imgsrc' alt='$option_name' >" ;
      print "<div id='orderSample' onclick='hideOrderSample();alert(\"order sample\");' ><b>+ Order Sample</b></div>" ;
      print "<p class='colorbook-color-subtitle'>$fullname</p>" ;
      //print "<p class='colorbook-color-subtitle'>$cbpg $space</p>" ;
    print "</div>" ;

}
```

And here's the CSS I have.

```
.colorbook-color-guide-div {
  width: 176px;
  min-height: 107px;
  margin-bottom: 2px;
  margin-right: 21px;
  cursor: pointer;
  float:left;
  text-align:center;
}
.colorbook-color-guide-image {
  width: 176px;
  min-height: 86px;
}
.colorbook-color-subtitle {
    font-family: HelveticaNeueLT-Light, Museo-500, Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
    font-style: normal ;
    font-weight:600 ;
    font-size: 13px ;
    font-size: 1.3rem ;
    color: #929496 ;
    margin-top: -3px;
}
#orderSample {
    height:0px;
    top:100px;
    width:176px;
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    background:white;
    opacity:.65;
}
```

And the JavaScript

```
function showOrderSample() {
  var element = document.getElementById("orderSample");
  element.style.height = "30px"; 
  element.style.top = "70px"; 
}

function hideOrderSample() {
    setTimeout(function () {
        document.getElementById("orderSample").style.height = "0px"; 
    }, 500);
}
```

Comment: you can find some examples to start with in this link http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28162888/text-overlay-on-image-hover-responsive . Few modifications should get you to your solution

Answer (score 1, accepted):

My example uses just JavaScript, html and fixed sizes but it does what was asked for.

Look at the Fiddle here:

https://jsfiddle.net/ag7to93q/9/

```
<script>
function showOrderSample(element) {   

  element.children[1].style.height = "30px"; // access the second child of the div element
  element.children[1].style.top = "70px"; 

}

function hideOrderSample(element, event) {
    if (event && event.target.classList.contains("hoverDiv")) {
        alert("buy buy buy!");
        setTimeout(function () {
            element.children[1].style.height = "0px"; 
        }, 200);
    }
    else {
// do something here
    }
}
</script>
<div style="position:absolute;top:50px;left:50px;width:200px;height:100px;background:green;" onmouseenter="showOrderSample(this);" onclick="hideOrderSample(this, event);" onmouseleave="hideOrderSample(this, event);" >
    <img style="position:absolute;height:100px;width:200px;" src="https://jsfiddle.net/img/logo.png" ></img>
    <div id="orderSample" class="hoverDiv" style="position:absolute;height:0px;top:100px;width:200px;display:block;overflow:hidden;background:white;opacity:.65;"><b>+ Order Sample<b>
    </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I was going to say it's missing something but you edited it ;) +1 because you have all of the elements OP asked for.

Comment: This seems to be exactly the route I'd like to take.  Now, I have one more level of complication.  There could be hundreds of these on the screen at one time.

Comment: I updated the answer so showOrderSample and hideOrderSample work on the element you attached them. You must not use the same id for more than one element.

Comment: There is a flaw in this approach that I am now just noticing.  The javascript is triggered by the mouseover event on the main, or first div.  By changing the the reference to "this" it's now changing the height of the main div to 30px instead of orderSample div.  So how do you refer to the div inside of the div when there could be hundreds of them on the same page?

Comment: @Tom you are right. We need to access the second child. This can be done using element.children[1].

Comment: @HaukeStenzel Ok - now it looks great.  Only one problem when I move off of the parent DIV I want the +Order Sample to go away same as it does when you click on it.  I though a mouse out on the parent DIV would take care of this but then the mouse out event fires as soon as you hover over the +Order Sample DIV.  Any thoughts on that?

Comment: I changed the event handling to check for onmouseenter and onmouseleave and to check only on the parent div. That is working better.

Comment: @HaukeStenzel - Is there a way that I could tell if they clicked on the Order Sample Div or if they clicked outside of that?  If they click on the Order Sample I want one thing to occur and if they click outside of it, then I want a different thing to occur.

Comment: @Tom you could pass the event object alongside the "this" and check the event.target property to see which diff or image was really clicked.

Comment: @Tom I added handling of the event to the Fiddle.

Answer (score 0):

Look at the following [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/AGE/3mpmt60w/). Keep in mind accurate answers require more detail, so based on your question I came up with an approximate (hopefully as accurate as possible) response. Let me know if it helped in getting you closer to where you want to be, we can work on something closer if needed.

HTML:

```
<div class="popup-overlay--gray">a</div>
<a class="popup-btn__open" href="#">Open Popup</a>

<div>
    <a class="popup-btn__close" href="#">Close Popup</a>
    <img class="popup" src="http://placehold.it/300x300"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
[class*="popup-btn"] { text-decoration: none; color: white; background-color: gray; }
.popup-btn__close { top: 0; right: 0; }
.popup { display: none; }
.popup-overlay--gray { position: absolute: width: 100%; height: 100%; background-color: #333; opacity: 0.7; z-index: 1000; }
```

jQuery 2.1.3

```
var timer,
    delay = 500;

$(".show-popup").hover(function(){
    // on mouse in, start a timeout
    timer = setTimeout(function(){
        // showing the popup
        $('.popup').fadeIn(500);
    }, delay);
}, function() {
    // on mouse out, cancel the timer
    clearTimeout(timer);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5uqounw6/)

Jquery solution

```
$('document').ready(function () {

    $('#myimage').hover(
    //hover in
    function () {
        $("#backgroundDIv").css('z-index', 101);
    },
    //hover out
    function () {
        $("#backgroundDIv").css('z-index', 99);
    });

});
```

HTML

```
<div id="mainDiv">
    <img id="myimage" src="http://i48.fastpic.ru/big/2013/0606/5c/aa5f8d03b34f8e79f18c07343573bc5c.jpg" />
    <input type="text" value="add me" id="backgroundDIv"/>
</div>
```

CSS

```
#myimage {
    z-index:100;
    position: absolute;
}
#backgroundDIv {
    z-index=99;
    position: absolute;
    top:200px;
    background-color:#fff200;
    opacity:0.4;
}
```